# XPC and Real-Time plotting

Tags: matlab, real-time, simulink

I'm new to using Simulink and XPC so the question might be trivial but I was unable to find an answer.

So, I need to make a simulink model that receives some data from positional sensors and by evaluating them I need to project something on the floor.

Since this was my first project with simulink I stared writing the Mathlab function, to try the code. I had the projector hooked up as a 2nd monitor and ploted my figure with the area function on the "2nd monitor".

After that I simulated the data I'd likely receive from the sensors with some sine functions just to check the code and to learn some simulink.

The problem I did not anticipated, because I've never used it before, is that when I hook up the sensors, I have to use the XPC for speed but suddenly plotting becomes an issue. Since its not windows my figure is not showing. Should it?

This seems like a large barrier and I do not know how to over come it. Is there a way to send the plot output via IP to another computer? Or some other work around.

Tnx in advance.
Vladimir

Comment: You could send the data from xPC to wherever you want to do the plotting via [UDP](https://de.mathworks.com/help/xpc/real-time-udp.html)

Comment: yeah, figured that today. do not know yet how to use it, but it will do the trick :) tnx!